# R Shiny (RStudio) capture keydown events

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

How can I capture keydown events (left/right/up/down or jlik for example) in a Shiny App? I think one way of doing this would be through some jquery on the webside.

Have seen lots of examples involving click events but have not found anything about keyboard events yet.